# Insert into table some values which are selected from other table

Tags: sql, database

I have my database structure like this ::

Database structure ::

- `ATT_table- ActID(PK), assignedtoID(FK), assignedbyID(FK), Env_ID(FK), Product_ID(FK), project_ID(FK), Status`
- `Product_table - Product_ID(PK), Product_name`
- `Project_Table- Project_ID(PK), Project_Name`
- `Environment_Table- Env_ID(PK), Env_Name`
- `Employee_Table- Employee_ID(PK), Name`
- `Employee_Product_projectMapping_Table -Emp_ID(FK), Project_ID(FK), Product_ID(FK)`
- `Product_EnvMapping_Table - Product_ID(FK), Env_ID(FK)`

I want to insert values in `ATT_Table`. Now in that table I have some columns like `assignedtoID`, `assignedbyID`, `envID`, `ProductID`, `project_ID` which are FK in this table but primary key in other tables they are simply numbers).

Now when I am inputting data from the user I am taking that in form of string like a user enters `Name` (`Employee_Table`), `product_Name` (`Product_table`) and not ID directly. So I want to first let the user enter the name (of `Employee` or `product` or `Project` or `Env`) and then value of its primary key (`Emp_ID, product_ID, project_ID, Env_ID`) are picked up and then they are inserted into `ATT_table` in place of `assignedtoID, assignedbyID, envID, ProductID, project_ID`.

Please note that `assignedtoID, assignedbyID` are referenced from `Emp_ID` in `Employee_Table`.

How to do this ? I have got something like this but its not working ::

```
INSERT INTO ATT_TABLE(Assigned_To_ID,Assigned_By_ID,Env_ID,Product_ID,Project_ID) 
VALUES (A, B, Env_Table.Env_ID, Product_Table.Product_ID, Project_Table.Project_ID)
SELECT Employee_Table.Emp_ID AS A,Employee_Table.Emp_ID AS B, Env_Table.Env_ID, Project_Table.Project_ID, Product_Table.Product_ID
FROM Employee_Table, Env_Table, Product_Table, Project_Table
WHERE Employee_Table.F_Name= "Shantanu" or Employee_Table.F_Name= "Kapil" or Env_Table.Env_Name= "SAT11A" or Product_Table.Product_Name = "ABC" or Project_Table.Project_Name = "Project1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **AND** instead of *OR*.

```
INSERT INTO ATT_TABLE(Assigned_To_ID,Assigned_By_ID,Env_ID,Product_ID,Project_ID) 
    SELECT A.Emp_ID, B.Emp_ID, Env_Table.Env_ID, Project_Table.Project_ID, Product_Table.Product_ID
    FROM Employee_Table A, Employee_Table B, Env_Table, Product_Table, Project_Table
    WHERE A.F_Name= "Shantanu" 
        AND B.F_Name= "Kapil" 
        AND Env_Table.Env_Name= "SAT11A" 
        AND Product_Table.Product_Name = "ABC" 
        AND Project_Table.Project_Name = "Project1";
```

But it is best practice to use drop down list in your scenario, i guess.

Comment: It keeps on giving me error insert; at the end of SQL statement. I guess its taking the end where i insert the values. after values when i insert ; and run it . It gives me an error text found after ; which is obvious. earlier also i am getting the same thing. Its not getting upto SELECT statement. thanks ..

Comment: Gives me ... You are about to append(0) rows... No data is added .. i think we need to have that VALUES Part...

Comment: @user1230183: No, in that case, there is no such matching data. Also there is an error. I am trying on it.

Comment: Hey i gt that ... Thanks ... Was making some mistake... Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: sarwar026 can u help me with this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041989/sql-query-to-perform-load-check-for-an-employee

Answer (score 2):

The way this is handled is by using drop down select lists. The list consists of (at least) two columns: one holds the Id's teh database works with, the other(s) store the strings the user sees. Like

```
1, "CA", "Canada"
2, "USA", 'United States"
...
```

The user sees

```
CA | Canada
USA| United States  
...
```

The value that gets stored in the database is 1, 2, ... whatever row the user selected.

You can never rely on the exact, correct input of users. Sooner or later they will make typo's.

---

I extend my answer, based on your remark.

The problem with the given solution (get the Id's from the parent tables by JOINing all those parent tables together by the entered text and combining those with a number of AND's) is that as soon as one given parameter has a typo, you will get not a single record back. Imagine the consequences when the real F_name of the employee is "Shant***anu***" and the user entered "Shant***aun***".

The best way to cope with this is to get those Id's one by one from the parent tables. Suppose some FK's have a NOT NULL constraint. You can check if the F_name is filled in and inform the user when he didn't fill that field. Suppose the user eneterd "Shant***aun***" as name, the program will not warn the user, as something is filled in. But that is not the check the database will do, because the NOT NULL constraints are defined on the Id's (FK). When you get the Id's one by one from the parent tables. You can verify if they are NOT NULL or not. When the text is filled in, like "Shant***aun***", but the returned Id is NULL, you can inform the user of a problem and let him correct his input: "No employee by the name 'Shantaun' could be found."

```
SELECT $Emp_ID_A = Emp_ID
FROM Employee_Table
WHERE F_Name= "Shantanu"

SELECT $Emp_ID_B = Emp_ID
FROM Employee_Table
WHERE B.F_Name= "Kapil" 

SELECT $Env_ID = Env_ID
FROM Env_Table
WHERE Env_Table.Env_Name= "SAT11A" 

SELECT $Product_ID = Product_ID
FROM Product_Table
WHERE Product_Table.Product_Name = "ABC" 

SELECT $Project_ID = Project_ID
FROM Project_Table
WHERE Project_Name = "Project1"
```

Comment: I know you are right.. that's the preferable way.. But i need to have that ID value in ATT_table.. Is it not possible what i have asked ? can we do that... ?